# Following pagination next page links is not working with scrapy. My CSS selector is not selecting the href for next page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape https://www.realtor.com/ to get rental information. I want to scrape all pages

I have been continuously having this problem of not being to follow the `href` to the next page using scrapy. I think my problem is I'm not actually selecting the `href` of the required `a` element.
Here's my code;

```
import scrapy

class RealtorScrape(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'realtor'
    allowed_domains = ['realtor.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Minneapolis_MN/']
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    def parse(self, response):      
        for house in response.css('li.jsx-1881802087 div.jsx-2775064451'):
            house_info = house.css('div.jsx-11645185.card-box')
            status =  house_info.css('div.jsx-11645185 div.jsx-3853574337 div.jsx-3853574337 span.jsx-3853574337::text').get()
            if status == 'For Sale':
                yield {
                    'Status': house_info.css('div.jsx-11645185 div.jsx-3853574337 div.jsx-3853574337 span.jsx-3853574337::text').get(),
                    'Price': house_info.css('div.jsx-11645185.detail-wrap .summary-wrap .property-wrap .srp-page-price span::text').get(),
                    'Beds': ' '.join(house_info.css('div.jsx-11645185.detail-wrap .summary-wrap .property-wrap .prop-meta .srp_listMeta .property-meta-srpPage li[data-label=pc-meta-beds] span::text').getall()),
                    'Baths': ' '.join(house_info.css('div.jsx-11645185.detail-wrap .summary-wrap .property-wrap .prop-meta .srp_listMeta .property-meta-srpPage li[data-label=pc-meta-baths] span::text').getall()),
                    'Square_feet': ' '.join(house_info.css('div.jsx-11645185.detail-wrap .summary-wrap .property-wrap .prop-meta .srp_listMeta .property-meta-srpPage li[data-label=pc-meta-sqft] span::text').getall()),
                    'Accre_lot': ' '.join(house_info.css('div.jsx-11645185.detail-wrap .summary-wrap .property-wrap .prop-meta .srp_listMeta .property-meta-srpPage li[data-label=pc-meta-sqftlot] span::text').getall()),
                    'Location': house_info.css('div.jsx-11645185.detail-wrap .summary-wrap .property-wrap .card-bottom div[data-label=pc-address]::text').get()
                    
                }
        next_page = response.css('div.jsx-1709448077.pagination-wrapper div.styles__StyledPaginator-rui__sc-1vqyfdo-0 a[aria-label=Go to next page]').attrib['href']
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

I would like to understand the real reason as to why I'm not able to follow scraping to the rest of the pages. Is my problem with the css selectors I have used to find the `next_page` `href`? Is `response` able to select any element on the page or is it limited?

I want to understand the real basic reason as to why this is failing so that I don't keep making this same mistake over and over again.

Thanks and I would like to get your support

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your selector is not working is because you need to quote attribute values that have spaces in them.

Your `next_page` selector :

```
next_page = response.css('div.jsx-1709448077.pagination-wrapper div.styles__StyledPaginator-rui__sc-1vqyfdo-0 a[aria-label=Go to next page]').attrib['href']
```

All you need to do to make your selector work is to add quotes the `Go to next Page`.

for example:

```
next_page = response.css('div.jsx-1709448077.pagination-wrapper div.styles__StyledPaginator-rui__sc-1vqyfdo-0 a[aria-label="Go to next page"]').attrib['href']
```

That is the "Real reason" why your selector was not working.

Comment: I didn't that this was the solution to being able to scrape the whole website... You asked "I would like to understand the real reason as to why I'm not able to follow scraping to the rest of the pages."  That is the question I answered. @KamalMoha